# Disable escape sequence syntax conversion in visual studio 2012 queries / db2 (odbc)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, db2, odbc

I'm connecting to a db2 database via Visual Studio 2012 and when I write a left join in my sql statement it converts it to escape sequence syntax.  Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening.  I've searched google for too long now.

Here is an example of my problem.

Here is the escape sequence syntax:

SELECT TICKETNUM, CUSNUM
FROM { oj TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN  HEADER ON TICKET.CUSNUM = HEADER.CUSNUM  }

This is what I entered originally and what I want it to be:

SELECT TICKETNUM, CUSNUM
FROM  TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN HEADER ON TICKET.CUSNUM = HEADER.CUSNUM

Comment: It looks like it thinks it's [talking to the SQL Server JDBC driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378045(v=sql.110).aspx) (although I'm not sure why that stuff needs to be escaped...).  You can't turn the escaping off for that driver - maybe you can [tell it to think like a different db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948772/visual-studio-thinks-correct-sql-syntax-is-incorrect)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option in VS 2012.  Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Do you have the IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio installed?